# Slot: access scope variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As a simplified example suppose you have this in a component called "my-buttons":

```
<button v-for='item in items' v-on:click="this.$emit('activate', item)">
    <slot>{{ item.name }}</slot>
</button>
```

If I use the component somewhere else, is there any way to override the slot **and** access the `item.name` value? For example:

```
<my-component items="myItems">
    <span class="myspecialstuff">{{ item.name }}</span>
</my-component>
```

Obviously as it stands now, vue will complain that it can not find `item` in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE2:
the following code does not work due to https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2511. I can't think of anything else. sorry.

UPDATE:

To achieve specific slot overriding, define slots as

```
<button v-for='item in items' v-on:click="this.$emit('activate', item)">
    <slot v-bind:name="'item-'+item.name">{{ item.name }}</slot>
</button>
```

and override as

```
<my-component items="myItems">
    //you have access to items so you can do this
    //specialItems is an array of items which are to be overriden
    <span class="myspecialstuff" v-for="item in specialItems" v-bind:slot="'item-'+item.name" >
        {{ item.name }}
    </span>
</my-component>
```

Original answer: 
that will be very convoluted imho.

there are 2 ways to achieve what you want depending on where `<my-component` is getting `items`.

1. `items` is passed to `my-component` as props. (most common case). In that case, you already have access to `items` and do not need to jump through hoops for it.
2. `<my-component>` is getting `items` through some external sources like a form or api.(less likely) in this case, you can either [raise events to pass data](http://vuejs.org/api/#events) or use [2-way bindings](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-bind) through `.sync`

Comment: I indeed have access to the items array in the scope of "my-components" but I do not have access to the currently selected item in the for loop which is what I need to update the slot content.

Comment: say, are you actually using the exact code you have posted here? because there are few problems with it. the way to access specific index varies with the way you are implementing it,

Comment: It's a simplified example of what I am using, not sure what would be wrong with it (assuming items is an array)? It works as well, it's simply the override with the slot that is failing.

Comment: the problem is in `<slot>` names, as you are using multiple slots and you want to override a specific slot, you need to give all those slots a nuique name. I am updating my answer to give you a code example

Comment: Not entirely what I'm looking for, I don't want to override a single specific item, I want to update the display for all items, hence the default slot usage.

Comment: the thing is `<slot>` are matched according to *name* ,not to the position or order. the way your code is written, a span tag will be generated for each item and list of all those tag will **match every single** `<slot>`

Comment: ok. I tried the code it does not work as `slot` attribute cannot be used with `v-bind`